# PHP array to be the same out to JSON format structure

Tags: php

Here's what I want to do in my php array to be exact json format below:

JSON

```
    {
"suggestions": [
    { "value": "Alex - alex@email.com", "data": {"id": 1, "name": Alex } },
    { "value": "John - john@email.com", "data": {"id": 2, "name": John } },
    { "value": "Diaz - diaz@email.com", "data": {"id": 3, "name": Diaz } }
]
}
```

Query result in my php array:

```
array( 
0 => array('id'=>'1' 'email'=>'alex@email.com', 'name'=>'Alex'), 
1 => array('id'=>'2' 'email'=>'john@email.com', 'name'=>'John'),
2 => array('id'=>'3' 'email'=>'diaz@email.com', 'name'=>'Diaz')
);
```

Do you have any idea how will you make my php array to that JSON format way?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you for your JSON format

```
 foreach($query as $key => $val){
    $json[$key]['value'] = $val['name']." - ".$val['email'];
    $json[$key]['data']["id"] = $val['id'];
    $json[$key]['data']["name"] = $val['name'];            
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use json_encode(); function for that.

```
json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($your_array as $key => $val) {
  foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
    if ($v == 'email') {
      //get the value of 'email' key in 'value'
      $newArr['suggestions']['value'] = current($v);
    }
    else {
      //if value is not email push it in 'data' key
      $newArr['suggestions']['data'] = $v;
    }
  }
}
//lastly encode the required array
echo json_encode($newArr);
```

Comment: @kenorb added the comments for explanation